# Tomcat JDBC connection pool reaches full capacity with XtraBackup

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, database-backups

I'm trying to workout a managed backup scheme on a production database with XtraBackup.

According to our DBA, XtraBackup doesn't lock the database, but issues a series of `SHOW TABLE STATUS` commands and then works on the file system level.

Still, just as XtraBackup runs my logs start to blow up with connection pool errors:

`Error getting database connection:[http-nio-8080-exec-5] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 10 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:10000].`

There's some suggestion that turning off `innodb-stats-on-metadata` might help so we're trying that.

At the same time I want to confirm my connection pool settings are good:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mydatabase_master"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          testOnReturn="false"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="30000"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
          maxActive="100"
          minIdle="10"
          maxWait="10000"
          initialSize="10"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
          jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
            org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
          username="db_user"
          password="mypassword"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://my.ip:3306/my_database"
          />
```

For everything besides the backup, this configuration works very well. Under most of our traffic the connection pool size hovers around the `initialSize`. It seems like setting the `maxActive` higher will just spawn new connections in the pool that are hanging.

Anything else seem like it could be tweaked in relation to XtraBackup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around, it looks like the issue is the strain XtraBackup puts on the database server. While XtraBackup doesn't use locking on all InnoDB databases, it still puts a strain on  the system. From the documentation

> "Although innobackupex does not block your database’s operation, any
>   backup can add load to the system being backed up. On systems that do
>   not have much spare I/O capacity, it might be helpful to throttle the
>   rate at which innobackupex reads and writes InnoDB data. You can do
>   this with the --throttle option."

We ended up just bumping up maxActive instead opting for throttling at this time. When XtraBackup initially runs, the queries are enough to slow the database down, causing the thread  pool to max out. Adding a higher level of maxActive connections allowed XtraBackup to run without maxing the connection pool.

It also seemed that turning `innodb-stats-on-metadata` to OFF helped speed up the `SHOW TABLE STATUS` queries, further lowering the strain on the DB.

Kind of a particular situation, but hopefully this will help anyone if they're in the same situation.